# React + Firebase Component does not re-render on data change (remove)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

This is a rendering / performance problem.

I've built a basic React App using Firebase. It basically works, with one notable anomalous behavior: rendering doesn't occur entirely on its own.

Specifically, I retrieve a list of groups to which a user belongs, and want to be able to add/remove groups, triggering a re-render. I'm using Firebase's .on('value'), .on('child_added'), and .on('child_removed') functions to bind references to these events.

Adding and removing groups works, however the group list disappears (especially noticed on remove), and I have to to click on a button (literally, any button in the UI) to bring it back (it pops up immediately, with all the correct data based on user action).

So - I'm clearly missing something somewhere, although I've been testing various fixes and have yet to be able to understand the issue. Components are:

Main Admin Component:

```
var React = require('react'),
    groupRef = new Firebase('http://my-url/groups'), //list of groups
    userRef = new Firebase('http://my-url/users'), //list of users
    groupListArray = [];

var AdminContainer = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactFireMixin],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            groups: []
        }
    },
    buildGroupList: function (dataSnapshot) {
        groupListArray = [];
        var groupList = dataSnapshot.val();
        /* The group ids are saved as children in the db
         * under users/$userid/groups to reflect which groups a user can
         * access - here I get the group ids and then iterate over the 
         * actual groups to get their names and other associated data under
         * groups/<misc info>
         */
        for (var key in groupList) {
            if (groupList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                groupRef.child(key).once('value', function(snapShot2) {
                    groupListArray.push(snapShot2);
                });
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            groups: groupListArray
        });
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        userRef.child(auth.uid).child('groups').on('value', this.buildGroupList);
        userRef.child(auth.uid).child('groups').on('child_removed', this.buildGroupList);
        userRef.child(auth.uid).child('groups').on('child_added', this.buildGroupList);
    },
    handleRemoveGroup: function(groupKey){
        userRef.child(auth.uid).child('groups').child(groupKey).remove(); 
    },
    render: function() {
        <div id="groupAdminDiv">
            <table id="groupAdminTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th>Group Name</th>
                         <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <GroupList groups={this.state.groups} remove={this.handleRemoveGroup} />
            </table>
        </div>
    }
});

module.exports = AdminContainer;
```

Then the GroupList Component:

```
var React = require('react');

var GroupList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var listGroups = this.props.groups.map((group, index) => {
            if (group != null) {
                return (
                    <tr key={index} className="u-full-width">
                        <td>
                            {group.val().group_name}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button className="button" onClick={this.props.remove.bind(null, group.key())}>Remove</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <tr>
                        <td>You have not added any Groups.</td>
                    </tr>
                )
            }
        });
        return (
            <tbody>
                {listGroups}
            </tbody>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = GroupList;
```

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was caused by use of `.once()`. As per Firebase's documentation, `.once()` is used to query a database location without attaching an enduring listener such as `.on('value', callBack)`. However, when I changed the instances in my code where I was calling `.once()` to use `.on()` (even though I didn't want to attach a listener there but instead simply retrieve data one time), all the erratic behavior stopped and my app updated `this.state` and components as I had originally expected it to.

The only thing I can take away from this experience is that `.once()` does not function as intended / stated and that `.on()` (plus appropriate `.off()` references) should be used instead.

Comment: I have the same problem but it makes no sense. If the data arrive either by `on` or `once` react should re-render regardless.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to already understand what you need. In your `componentWillMount` method you register for various `userRef` events. You just need to register for the `groupRef` events, using the same callback. React re-renders whenever a components `setState` method is called, which you are doing inside `buildGroupList`. You just need to call `buildGroupList` after the `groupRef` updates.

```
componentWillMount: function() {
        var events = ['value', 'child_removed', 'child_added'];
        var refs = [groupRef, userRef.child(auth.uid).child('groups')];
        var callback = this.buildGroupList;
        refs.forEach(function(ref) {
            events.forEach(function(e) {
                ref.on(e, callback);
            });
        });
    },
```

Comment: I do like the cleaner code (a lot - thx), but unfortunately nothing is triggering a re-render apart from clicking on a button / link on the page. The group list is actually built from the groups listed in the User profile data, and that is what is being "watched" by ref.on(). When I remove a group, the whole list disappears & the group is removed in the Firebase db, but the table isn't redrawn until there is an additional user action (clicking a button / link). However then the list pops up, and is correct. Strange...

Comment: I'm having a hard time following all of that. Is there any chance you can reproduce this with CodePen?

Comment: I will see if I can throw this onto a production environment with dummy data & disable login. I'll post up the link when done - really appreciate the help.